# function getTimestamp() on a non-object

Tags: php, datetime

i assign a date as string to the datetimepicker `16/01/2016 09:34:02`

```
$ddate=get_field('ddate',$post->ID);
echo $ddate;
$ddate=date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:m:s',$ddate);   

var_dump($ddate);
```

but in var_dump i get the output as `object(DateTime)#725 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-10-16 09:00:02.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }` 
but when i echo the ddate it echos is correctly.

basically the wrong date i am unable to figure out the error plz guide

Comment: $ddate=date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:m:i:s',$ddate);

Comment: nope it gives bool(false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the minutes format from "m" to "i".

```
$ddate="16/01/2016 09:34:02";
$ddate=date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s',$ddate);
var_dump($ddate);</code>
```

Please refer the formats [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_create_from_format.asp/).